# delete an active x combobox with vba

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, activex

I have a sheet where, on selection of a cell, create an activex combo box on the line and a delete button.

When the user press the delete button it is supposed to delete the whole line.

```
Rows(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.row).Delete
```

It effectively deletes everything but the activex combobox.
How it can be deleted?

Code:

```
Dim cb as ComboBox
Set cb = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=Cells(cfgRows+1,1).Left, Top:=Cells(cfgRows+1,1)).Top, Width:=Cells(cfgRows+1,1).width, Height:=Cells(cfgRows+1,1).height).Object

cb.Name = cfgRows + 1
```

On the web I have only found ways to delete all the comboboxes in the sheet

Comment: I guess that combobox got a name. Can you use that to delete it?

Comment: I didn't assign any name since they are supposed to be added dinamically in an indefinite number.
I was hoping in a solution starting by the number of the row but I don't manage to refer to the combobox presents in the row like in the sheet

Comment: Did you mean `Application.Caller` instead of `ApplicationCaller`?

Comment: yes of course. It s a typo.

Comment: If you don't keep track of your comboboxes I believe you need to loop through all of them and look at where they are positioned. Doesn't sound very efficient

Comment: You can rename your combobox as you add them. Will be easier to delete in the future.

Comment: I have a 'Error defined for the application or the object' if I try to set a name with an integer var. Ex:
cb.Name = cfgRows +1 where cfgRows is an Integer

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code you use to create and change the name of the combobox?

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: The name is attached to the `OLEObject`, not to the `ComboBox`. Try `ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=Cells(cfgRows+1,1).Left, Top:=Cells(cfgRows+1,1)).Top, Width:=Cells(cfgRows+1,1).width, Height:=Cells(cfgRows+1,1).height).Name = cfgRows + 1`.

Comment: Now it raises an 'Object requested' error. Anyway I'd like to use the .Object properties in order to additems and set linkedcell later using cb.
I am not very familiar with this component

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since this post was made; in the other hand I'd like to offer some workaround in the case others might need it.

So, since a ComboBox can be found inside the OLEObjects, you can find it by the name you gave to it in the moment of creation.

*Example*: In the case you have the "ComboBox99" name, inside a string **variable**, you could use:

```
Dim combo As Object

For Each combo In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    If TypeName(combo.Object) = "ComboBox" Then
        If combo.name = "ComboBox99" Then combo.delete
    End If
Next
```

### Practical Example

So, for the first step is to go to a normal module and paste this script. And use it in a **blank Sheet**. This will generate: 1 *ComboBox*, 1 *CommandButton* and, print 1 *Text* in the right side. (But you can augment the **i** value of the 'for', in case of you wanto to do mores tests)

```
Sub CreateComboAndButton()

Dim combo As OLEObject, button As OLEObject
Dim c, a, t

With ActiveSheet
    .rows.RowHeight = 20

    'Augment 'i' to create more than one.
    For i = 1 To 1
    
    
        Set c = .Cells(i, 1):
            a = c.row
    
            
        Set combo = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
            Left:=c.Left, _
            top:=c.top, _
            width:=c.width, _
            height:=c.height _
        )
        
        
        Set button = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
            Left:=c.width + 2, _
            top:=c.top, _
            width:=15, _
            height:=c.height _
        )
        
        .Cells(i, 3) = "SomeTextInRow" & c.row  '//Add some text
        
        combo.name = "ComboBox_" & a
        button.name = "CommandButton_" & a: button.Object.fontSize = 7: button.Object.Caption = "X"
        Debug.Print (combo.name & " || " & button.name)
        
    Next
End With



End Sub
```

### Triggered Event

Finally, paste the next script inside the **worksheet itself**, not in a module.

This script, will first iterate every  *Objects* inside *OLEObjects* for the specific **TypeName** of our objects (which are: ComboBox and CommandButton) later will chech the name of the object itself and compare it to:"ComboBox_1" (which is the name of the Combo we created previously), and will delete it. It does the same in the second **'for'**, to delete the name of the CommandButton we named: "CommandButton_1".

**Tip:**
The row is deleted using the **row index** given by the CommandButton property, so we can always delete the exactly row where our objects are, even if the user previously had elimanted some rows before.

```
Private Sub CommandButton_1_Click()

Dim combo As Object, button As Object
On Error GoTo nameChanged:
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    myCombo = "ComboBox_1"
    myButton = "CommandButton_1"


    For Each combo In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(combo.Object) = "ComboBox" Then
            If combo.Name = myCombo Then combo.Delete
        End If
    Next


    For Each Button In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        Debug.Print (TypeName(Button.Object))
        If TypeName(Button.Object) = "CommandButton" Then
            If Button.Name = myButton Then
                r = Button.TopLeftCell.Row
                Button.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next

    
    ActiveSheet.Rows(r).Delete



nameChanged:
Resume Next


End Sub
```

### Brief Explanation

So, to put this scripts to work, click on the "X" button, so the entire row can be deleted.